# Creating a XML file using Transformer object having ":" in the file name

Tags: xml, transformer-model

How can I create a XML file in linux server which have the ":" in the file name, like:

```
outputXMLFile = new File("/data/file/Test_2015-03-16T09:34:171");
outputXMLFile.createNewFile();
StreamResult result1 = new StreamResult(outputXMLFile);
transformer.transform(source1, result1);
```

I am getting the error : no such file or directory.

Any other workaround, I have a Document object which is possibly very big in size.

Comment: `:` is a Special character in file names. Do not use it if you can. If not  escape it with a backslash.

Comment: yes, I understand, but my requirement is - I already have a XML (having ':' ), and I have to update and create a new XML file, by appending the _Final.xml, So I don't want to disturb the original File name.

Comment: @Jens I tried to give "/:"  and "\:" and "//:" and "\\:", but it didn't work. Any sugestion?